# Compare two tables in Python and return rows that have changed

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have two tables with very similar data (similar but not identical data) they are generated daily.

Sample Table RT20190101

```
Time    Sensor  Name    StaTus  Reading Temp    Grade   Acidity
20190101-830,   A345CRT,    XXXXXXX,    Active, 5.6,    54, 8,  3.2
20190101-930,   A445ADE,    XXXXXXX,    Active, 5.5,    54, 8,  1.2
20190101-1030,  D546RTE,    XXXXXXX,    Active, 5.5,    55, 8,  2
20190101-1130,  D678FRT,    XXXXXXX,    De-Active,  5.7,    57, 7,  3.5
```

Sample Table RT20190102

```
Time    Sensor  Name    StaTus  Reading Temp    Grade   Acidity
20190102-830,   A345CRT,    XXXXXXX,    Active, 5.6,    54, 8,  3.2
20190102-930,   A445ADE,    XXXXXXX,    De-Active,  5.6,    56, 7,  1.2
20190102-1030,  D546RTE,    XXXXXXX,    De-Active,  5.5,    56, 8,  2
20190102-1130,  D678FRT,    XXXXXXX,    Active, 5.5,    56, 9,  2
```

I would like to compare Sensor on both files and flag them, where TEMP, Grade and Acidity have changed.

I can solve this problem using SQL but would like to replicate following code in Python

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT A.Time, B.Time, B.Sensor, B.Name, A.Status, B.Status, 
            IIf(A.Status<>B.Status,1,0) AS StatusChange, A.[Reading], B.[Reading], 
            IIf([A.Reading]<>[B.Reading],1,0) AS [Reading Change], 
            iif(A.Temp<>B.Temp,1,iif([A.Grade]<>[B.Grade],1,iif([A.Acidity]<>[B.Acidity],1,0))) AS Change 
    FROM RT20190101 AS A INNER 
    JOIN RT20190102 AS B ON A.Time = B.Time)
WHERE Change=1;
```

Sample Output

```
A.Time  B.Time  Sensor  Name    A.Status    B.Status    StatusChange    A.Reading   B.Reading   Reading Change
20190101-1130,  20190102-1130,  D678FRT,    XXXXXXX,    De-Active,  Active, 1,  5.7,    5.5,    1
```

I want to get a list of all Sensor, their names, if their status changed and if reading changed. Only when `TEMP`, `GRADE` and `ACIDITY` level also changed.

Comment: Can you please post sample input data and expected output?

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: input and expected output would really help. also any attempt at code to show you have tried.

Comment: Updated my questions with sample data

Comment: Can  you just paste your sample data and output in the question as links wont last forever and also we cant copy and paste your data into our code to help you solve this

Comment: Yes I am using Pandas @Barmar

Comment: I updated my questions and removed links @ChrisDoyle

Answer (score 0):

Just a general idea:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_sql_table('first_table', 'postgres:///db_name')
df2 = pd.read_sql_table('second_table', 'postgres:///db_name')

df1['compare'] = np.nan
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
      id = df1['id'].loc[i]
      sensor1 = df1['sensor'].loc[i]
      sensor2 = df2['sensor'].loc[df2['id'] == id]
      if sensor1 != sensor2:
          df1['compare'].loc[i] = False
      else:
          df1['compare'].loc[i] = True
```